# Why aren't my videos loading on IE and Edge after windows update KB4343909?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, video.js

After installing [Windows 10 update KB4343909](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4343909/windows-10-update-kb4343909), videos loaded on my site have stopped loading. They are loaded through video.js, and which just stays on readyState=0 and networkState=0, without ever coming up with an error.

Everything still works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. just not IE and Edge.

The js code looks something like this:

```
var video_module = videojs("my-video");
video_module.ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  $('.video-js').append(loading);
});

video_module.load();

var loadingCheck = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(video_module.networkState() >= 1){
    $('.vjs-big-play-button').css('opacity', 1);
    $('.loading-spinner').remove();
    clearInterval(loadingCheck);
  }
  if(loadingCount === 15){
    if(video_module.src() == '' || video_module.readyState() < 1){
      video_module.dispose();
      //Show timeout message...
      clearInterval(loadingCheck);
    }
  }
  loadingCount++;
}, 1000);
```

And the html is something like this:

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="none"
    data-setup="{}">
  <source src="my/video/url" type="video/mp4">
  <p class="vjs-no-js">No HTML5 video message...</p>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to have been the `preload="none"`. Changing it to `preload="auto"` fixed the issue in Edge.

According to the update, it:

> Ensures that Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge support the preload="none" tag.

My guess at why this behaved the way it did, was that this was preventing the user from loading the video (by clicking on it), with a check on `networkState`, but networkState only gets to 1 once it starts loading the video, so without a preload, it essentially deadlocks. That's the theory anyway.